# ServiceMix + Camel transactional producer

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic, apache-servicemix

I'm trying to send a messasge into an ActiveMQ queue from a web service which is deployed to ServiceMix 5.4.0. For that reason I obtain a producer template from the camel context and send the message in the following way:

```
ProducerTemplate template = camelContext.createProducerTemplate();
template.send(
    "activemq://ExecutePaymentInputQueue",
    new Processor() {
        @Override
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
            exchange.getIn().setBody(
                ...
            );
        }
    }
);
```

The relevant parts from the blueprint.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:cm="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.1.0"
    xmlns:jpa="http://aries.apache.org/xmlns/jpa/v1.1.0"
    xmlns:tx="http://aries.apache.org/xmlns/transactions/v1.0.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
  http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd
  http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint-ext/v1.1.0 https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/aries/tags/blueprint-0.3.1/blueprint-core/src/main/resources/org/apache/aries/blueprint/ext/blueprint-ext.xsd  
  http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/blueprint/jaxws.xsd
  http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/jaxrs http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/blueprint/jaxrs.xsd
  http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/core http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/blueprint/core.xsd
  http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/camel-blueprint.xsd
  ">

    <!-- Transaction manager setup -->
    <reference id="jtaTransactionManager" interface="javax.transaction.TransactionManager"/>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">
        <argument ref="jtaTransactionManager"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Transaction policy setup -->
    <bean id="DefaultTransactionPolicy" class="org.apache.camel.spring.spi.SpringTransactionPolicy">
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- BEGIN ActiveMQ -->

    <bean id="activemqConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
        <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://localhost:61616" />
        <property name="userName" value="smx"/>
        <property name="password" value="smx"/>

        <property name="redeliveryPolicy">
            <bean class="org.apache.activemq.RedeliveryPolicy">
                <property name="maximumRedeliveries" value="360"/>
                <property name="redeliveryDelay" value="10000"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jmsConfig" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="activemqConnectionFactory"/>
        <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="8"/>
        <property name="maxConcurrentConsumers" value="16"/>
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="activemq" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
        <property name="configuration" ref="jmsConfig" />
    </bean>

    <!-- JMS component setup -->
    <!--<reference id="connectionFactory" interface="javax.jms.ConnectionFactory" />-->

    <!-- END ActiveMQ -->

    <!-- BEGIN SERVICE EXPORTS -->
    <service interface="com.bssys.ebpp.core.api.PaymentService" >
        <bean class="com.bssys.ebpp.core.services.impl.PaymentServiceImpl">
            <tx:transaction method="*" value="Required"/>
        </bean>
    </service>
    <!-- END SERVICE EXPORTS -->

    <camelContext id="camelContext" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint"
                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  xsi:schemaLocation="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/camel-blueprint-2.13.2.xsd">

       ...

    </camelContext>

</blueprint>
```

When the message is sent there should be an open JTA transaction (see the declarative aries configuration in blueprint.xml).

The problem is that the producer seems to ignore the jta transaction, and the message is being put to the destination queue outside that transaction (immediately after the send method returns). How can change this behaviour and make the producer join the JTA transaction?